# Why executing window.location.href two times, only last time work?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web

open console and input

```
window.location.href="https://www.youtube.com"
window.location.href="https://www.google.com"
```

only the last time work, why?
[image]

Comment: you can't have two pages loaded at the same time in the same window

Comment: @xianshenglu No, you can look at the "network" page, not working

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, but i wonder why?

Comment: Perhaps the browser waits for the stack to clear before performing the navigation, which would use the last value set

Comment: because browsers don't work that way

Comment: @Sidney I also guess so. Can you make it more detailed?

Comment: when the code has been excuted,the `window.location.href` would be the last value.Is there anything unreasonable?may be you need  this`window.open("https://www.youtube.com");
window.open("https://www.google.com")`